# Field of fractions of etale stalk of Dedekind domain (Example from Milne's LEC)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, etale-cohomology

Let $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ be an affine [Dedekind domain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain#Alternative_definitions) with field of fractions $K$. Let $\widetilde{A}$ be the integral closure of $A$ in separable closure $ K^{\text{sep}}$. A closed point $x$ of $X$ is a nonzero prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$, and the choice of a prime ideal $\widetilde{p}$ of $\widetilde{A}$ lying over  $\mathfrak{p}$ determines a geometric point $\overline{x}= \operatorname{Spec}k(x)^{\text{sep}} \to X$ a geometric point of $X$. The etale stalk with respect to $\overline{x}$ is given by

$$ \mathcal{O}_{X,\overline{x}}^{\text{et}}=  \varinjlim_{(A_U,u) \text{ etale nbhds of } A \text{ over }\overline{x}} (A_U,u)$$

**Question:** How to see that the field of fractions of the ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,\overline{x}}^{\text{et}}$ equals to the fixed field $(K^{\text{sep}})^{I(\widetilde{\mathfrak{p}})}$ where the inertia group $I(\widetilde{\mathfrak{p}})$ of $\widetilde{\mathfrak{p}}$ is defined as

$$I(\widetilde{\mathfrak{p}})=:\{ g \in G \ | \ g(\widetilde{\mathfrak{p}})=\widetilde{\mathfrak{p}} \text{ and } g | _{\kappa(\widetilde{\mathfrak{p}})}  = \text{id}_{\kappa(\widetilde{\mathfrak{p}})} \} \subset \text{Gal}(K^{\text{sep}}/K)$$

Source: Milne's LEC script on Etale Cohomology (Example 12.4, page 82 last paragraph)

Note that previous considerations in the linked script show that the field of fractions of the ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,\overline{x}}^{\text{et}}$ is given by inductive limit of those finite separable field extensions $L/K$ ( contained in $ K^{\text{sep}}$) such that the normalization $X_L$ of $ X$ in $L$ is unramified at some point lying over $x$, but I not see why this inductive limit equals in this case to $(K^{\text{sep}})^{I(\widetilde{\mathfrak{p}})}$ as claimed. Especially, how the requirement that normalization $X_L$ of $ X$ in $L$ is unramified at some point lying over $x$ is related to the property of $L$ being fixed by the inertia group $I(\widetilde{\mathfrak{p}})$.

Thematically the problem is closely related to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452621/calculate-stalk-of-etale-derived-pushforward-sheaf-milnes-lec) question I asked before.

Ideas: Here a way to reduce the problem at least to finite extension case. There exist a finite extension $M/K$, such that the associated map $\overline{x}= \operatorname{Spec}k(x)^{\text{sep}} \to X$ to the considered geometric point factors scheme theoretically through $X_M$, the Spec of integral closure of $A$ in $M$. So we can assume that all field extensions discussed about about to be finite and we can replace avove everywhere  $ K^{\text{sep}}$ by finite extension $M$, letting the inertia group living inside a finite Galois group.

But not see how to proceed from here.

Comment: @Vik78 The henselation of $\mathbf Z$ at $p$ is ind-étale over $\mathbf Z$, and therefore countable, by construction. It is not $\mathbf Z_p$.

Comment: Right thanks, my mistake

Comment: See also Prop. 2.3.11, p. 50 in the book Néron Models by Bosch et al.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Milne (sort of) explains, the following two data are exactly the same:

1. A connected étale neighbourhood $U \to X$ with a lift $\bar x \to U$ of $\bar x \to X$, up to shrinking Zariski-locally around the image of $\bar x$ in $U$ (I suppose you could call these 'Zariski germs of connected étale neighbourhoods');
2. A finite separable field extension $K \to L$ together with a prime $\mathfrak q$ above $\mathfrak p$ in the integral closure $B$ of $A$ in $L$, together with a map $\kappa(\mathfrak q) \to \kappa(\bar x)$, such that the map $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is étale at $\mathfrak q$.

Indeed, to pass from (1) to (2), we saw in [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/452621/82179) to your previous question that the generic fibre of $U \to X$ is a field if $U$ is connected, and $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A = X$ is étale at $\mathfrak q$ by assumption. Conversely, to go from (2) to (1), we may for instance take $U$ to be the (open) locus of $\operatorname{Spec} B$ where $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is étale, which is nonempty since it contains the generic point (as $K \to L$ is separable).

The choice of $\mathfrak q$ above $\mathfrak p$ together with the map $\kappa(\mathfrak q) \to \kappa(\bar x)$ can be taken care of by choosing a prime ideal $\widetilde{\mathfrak p}$ in $\widetilde A$ together with an isomorphism $\kappa\big(\widetilde{\mathfrak p}\big) \stackrel\sim\to \kappa(\bar x)$. So the only thing to think about is when $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is étale at $\mathfrak q := \widetilde{\mathfrak p} \cap B$. Standard Galois ramification theory tells us that $(\bar K)^{I(\widetilde{\mathfrak p})}$ is the unique largest subfield of $\bar K$ such that for any finite subextension $K \to L \to (\bar K)^{I(\widetilde{\mathfrak p})}$, the map $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is étale at $\mathfrak q := \widetilde{\mathfrak p} \cap B$ (where as usual $B$ is the integral closure of $A$ in $L$). A sample reference is Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory*, Ch. I, Prop. 9.6.

Comment: I think there’s a subtlety here: you are implicitly thinking of finite separable field extensions $K \to L$ as sitting inside a fixed $K^{sep}$.   This is how the geometric point $\overline{x}$ over $\mathfrak{p}$ remembers the prime ideal $\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}$ which induces it: if we have a finite separable $K \to L$ and an unramified prime $\mathfrak{q}$ over $\mathfrak{p}$ in $B$, we can always conjugate by an element $\sigma$ of Gal($K^{sep}/K)$ so that $\sigma{\mathfrak{q}} = \tilde{\mathfrak{p}} \cap B$. The coset $\sigma I(\tilde{\mathfrak{p}})$ is determined by $\mathfrak{q}$,

Comment: so we get a natural embedding $L \to (K^{sep})^{I(\tilde{\mathfrak{p}})}$. So a choice of $\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}$ gives a canonical isomorphism to this field. which is not encoded by a geometric point over $\mathfrak{p}$ alone.

Comment: Perhaps that should say instead: the data of the etale neighborhood determines $\sigma$  as a map $L \to K^{sep}$ (up to composition with elements of $I(\tilde{p}))$,and therefore induces a natural map $L \to (K^{sep})^{I(\tilde{p})}$. Taking the limit we get our desired isomorphism

Comment: one nitpick: the assumption was that $X$ is Dedekind scheme, in of dimension one $1$ and therefore the tools from classical  algebraic theory for number fields fit here. Nevertheless, if we start with arbitrary local normal ring $A$ with field of fractions $K$, any separable extension field extension $L$ and intergral closure $B$ of $A$ in $L$, then picking an maximal ideal $p$ of $B$ lying over the max ideal $m$ of $A$, allows still to define decomposition and inertia subgroups wrt $p \subset B$ inside the Galois group of $L/K$. So the terminology also makes sense for higher dimension.

Comment: Now the natural question is if the result above that the field of fractions of  $\mathcal{O}_{X,\overline{x}}^{\text{et}}$ equals to the fixed field $(K^{\text{sep}})^{I(\widetilde{\mathfrak{p}})}$ still could work, if we weaken our "Dedekind assumption" to "normality"only, ie in higher dimensional setting?

Comment: In other words, how much of the Galois ramification theory applied in above setting still survive in higher dimension?

Comment: I did see your [other \(previously bountied\) question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/429107/82179), but the answer is I don't really know! What makes it difficult (to me) is that the finite map $X' \to X$ is no longer flat, so you can't argue by degree counting. For instance, I haven't thought about classical questions like whether Galois acts transitively on the fibre (in some scheme-theoretic way?), although I assume this is known.

Comment: Just to clarify: What do you mean in this context by the "degree counting argument" ( which seemingly only work if the considered map is flat)? A guess: Do you refer by this to the additivity of the field  extension degrees with resp the composition of field extensions, which in turn carry information about ramification behavior in this sense: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_of_prime_ideals_in_Galois_extensions#Definitions . Or mean by "argue by degree counting" another issue?

Comment: By degree counting, I mean the statement that $\Gamma(f^{-1}(x),\mathcal O_{f^{-1}(x)})$ is a $\kappa(x)$-algebra of dimension $[L:K]$ if $f \colon Y \to X$ is a finite extension of normal schemes with generic fibre $K \to L$ (and $x \in X$ is any point). This holds in the flat case (e.g. for Dedekind schemes), but not in general. (This approach is useful because Milne's Thm. 3.21 shows that the étale locus agrees with the unramified locus, and checking that something is unramified can be done fibrewise.)

Comment: Theorem 41.2 in Nagata's Local Rings provides - if I'm not missing something - an argument without flatness assumption. This should give the full answer to my concern in "one nitpick" comment above